# ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initlibpyuno)

Tags: python, python-import, libreoffice

I have installed Eclipse IDE with Python, I'm trying to setup an environment for writing some python scripts to automate Libre Office, I have made a script with just one line of code for now ("`import libpyuno`"), when i run this line of code i get an error:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initlibpyuno)
```

I have added `"usr/lib/libreoffice/program"` as external library path.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supported way of using pyuno is to invoke the python interpreter bundled with LibreOffice itself. If you want to use an existing interpreter, then you need to make sure you manually do the same setup as the python shell script does inside the LibreOffice installation set (`/usr/lib/libreoffice`) in your case. This involves not only setting `PYTHONPATH` but at least specifying `URE_BOOTSTRAP` as well (both are environment variables.)

Now to your actual question: you probably don't want to import `libpyuno`. If you want to import a single LibreOffice-specific Python module for testing, then import just `uno`.

See https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/scripting/examples/python/NamedRanges.py for a real-world pyuno script, you can see even that only needs the `uno` module.